# android setNegativeButton to custom dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have my own custom dialog like this:

```
public class BerekenDialog extends Dialog{
    public BerekenDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.bereken_dialog_layout);

        this.setTitle("Bereken");
        //dostuff.
    }
}
```

I start my dialog with this:

```
BerekenDialog bd = new BerekenDialog (this);
bd.show();
```

Is there a way to add the negative, positive and neutral button from the alertdialog to my custom dialog?

Comment: Just add the buttons you want to `R.layout.bereken_dialog_layout.xml`?

Comment: post the bereken_dialog_layout.xml

Comment: @codeMagic I'm not talking about regular buttons. I'm talking about buttons like in this picture: http://developer.android.com/images/ui/dialogs_regions.png

Comment: What's not "regular" about those?

Comment: @codeMagic They look pretty fancy compared to unstyled buttons

Comment: you need to use AlertDialog to use the positive and negative button creation. All that is, is a button with the style of `buttonBarButtonStyle` and that is what `AlertDialog` uses

Comment: @RobinDijkhof what are you trying to achive in custom dialog?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin get data from some spinners, make a calculation with the data and display it

Comment: @tyczj this puts the button at the buttom, do you know how to add the small lines and the onclick color?

Answer (score 2):

```
get data from some spinners, make a calculation with the data and display it
```

You can do that without creating a custom dialog, positive and negative buttons are only made when you are creating it in the builder. There is no way to achieve it instead you can create you own in the xml layout with buttons.

creating alertdialog without using a custom one:

```
    AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Bereken")
    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.bereken_dialog_layout,null))
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // ok button
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // cancel button
        }
     }).create();
    TextView tv = (TextView)a.findViewById(r.id.your_id); //use the instance of textview from layout of dialog
    tv.setText("update"); //set is before displaying
    a.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 2 buttons, and make them look like the ones in the AlerDialog.Builder.

[image]

You create the 2 buttons, you just need to change their background color and add some borders around them. This can be done by creating a drawable (button_border_shape) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bdbdbd" />
    <solid android:color="#f2f2f2" />
</shape>
```

Then you'll need to apply this drawable as a background color to the button in your custom dialog xml :

```
android:background="@drawable/button_border_shape"
```